# How to escape "?" using regex in .htaccess for mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to escape the "?" character in the url, so that it works with rewritten urls like search/why-is-it?-1.html

I currently have the following in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?search=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Don't put a question mark in your URLs. The `?` is reserved for the start of the query string.

To place it in a URL, encode it as `%3F`.

Read the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547922#1547922).

#### Update

If using PHP (and it looks like you are), you could do something like this (page requested is `index.php/inter?net`)...

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET);

$urlTokens = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$slug = end($urlTokens);

var_dump($slug);
```

#### Outputs

```
array(1) {
  ["net"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

string(9) "inter?net"
```

You can see `$_GET` is confused.

Comment: Yes, That's what I do, but it becomes inaccessible when linked from Google or Facebook, That's the problem (They decode the url which is normal). I've seen some sites (using mod_rewrite) with similar urls, which allows putting "?" in the url without affecting anything..  That's why I asked if there is anyway to escape it or encode it using regex (.htaccess / mod_rewrite)

Comment: @slimb Can you link to these URLs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is the query doesn't get passed/sent to the php file so I can manipulate it.. It just, once I put a "?" in the url it returns a 404 error.

Comment: @slimb Did you use the code I used above? Why do you so badly want a `?` in your URL? Being against the RFC, it may break at any time.